# AlertDialog not dismissing by tapping on background on Samsung devices

Tags: android, react-native, android-alertdialog

I am using `AlertDialog` (full disclosure: using React Native, but this is using Native code and bridged through the Native Modules API so I don't think RN is causing the issue) in the app I develop for displaying a menu of items, which works perfectly in all cases. I developed it using the Pixel 2 simulator (API 28, Android 9). However, when testing on a Samsung device (Galaxy S4, Android 5), the dialog is not dismissable by touching the background of the app; I can only cancel it when pressing the back button. Here is the code I am using:

```
@ReactMethod
public void showDialog(ReadableArray labelsReadableArray, final Promise promise) {
    final String[] labels = getLabels(labelsReadableArray);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getCurrentActivity())
        .setItems(labels, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int itemIndex) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                promise.resolve(itemIndex);
            }
        })
        .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                promise.reject("dialog was closed");
            }
        }).setCancelable(true)
        .show();
}
```

and in the React Native code I call:

```
NativeModules.AndroidPicker.showDialog(labels)
  .then((index) => /* JS/redux action to process the change)
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Why is the Samsung device not cancelling the dialog when the background is tapped, while other Android phones do? How can I fix this?

Comment: `.setDismissable(true)`

Comment: I have no problem on TouchWiz Oreo with cancellable dialogs. Have you tried using an emulator on Lollipop to see if it's a Samsung-specific issue?

Comment: @TheWanderer yeah I've run a Nexus 4 with Lollipop, the dialog is cancellable. ChristopheCVB, `.setDismissable(true)` isn't available and throws up an error.

Comment: Is this a support AlertDialog or a framework AlertDialog (does the import line contain `support` or not)?

Comment: check is there any`setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`?

Comment: @TheWanderer The two imports for AlertDialog are `import android.app.AlertDialog;` and 
`import android.content.DialogInterface;`, so no `support`. Amiya, I had found that method before but it's not available.

Comment: You should try using the support version then: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog. You may need to add a dependency for it. I'm not sure if React uses Gradle or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution to dismiss the `AlertDialog` by tapping on the background on Samsung devices:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;
  alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
  alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```